# Teradata / Window functions - QUALIFY

Tags: sql, teradata, window-functions

I'm analyzing the code of my collegue. 
Found this query:

```
SELECT 
     client_id
from lib.applications
QUALIFY Row_Number() Over(PARTITION BY client_id ORDER BY closed) = 1
WHERE closed=0 and application_date > '2016-01-01'
```

Logically, the query should return a list of clients with active (not closed) applications. 
I can't uderstand, why he used `QUALIFY etc..` here? 
The request below is simplier and returns the same:

```
SELECT 
     client_id
from lib.applications
WHERE closed=0 and application_date > '2016-01-01'
```

Do you have any idea, for what reason QUALIFY could be used here?

Comment: `qualify` is being used to return one row per `client_id`.

Answer (score 1):

`QUALIFY` is returning one row per `client_id`.  The more colloquial way of writing the query would be:

```
SELECT DISTINCT client_id
FROM lib.applications
WHERE closed = 0 and application_date > '2016-01-01';
```

Perhaps the author of the query checked performance and found that `QUALIFY` is faster in this case (although I would doubt that).  Perhaps the author was thinking of including other columns, in which case `SELECT DISTINCT` would not work.

Comment: thx. and If, for example, I had several active (closed=0) applications for one client_id, and I needed to return client_id + application_id, how QUALIFY would choose one row?

Comment: @GrigoryP . . . It is returning the row with the oldest `closed` value for each `client_id`.